# Building a new country, building industry from scratch

Tags: geopolitics

A new country is forming in northern Australia, settlement efforts have begun, hundreds of citizens are working together to build a new city.

We are dominating an informational war and are slowly becoming recognised as a developing, but considered a majorly unrecognised nation or autonomous region of Australia

### How do we economically sustain ourselves & develop industry

To give some context, our government is trying to develop a highly efficient digital government for the majority of our services, removing bureaucracy and reducing the need for staff and therefore large costs. Examples include:

- Fully digitized licensing services
- Online business registration (we want to make starting a business in our country as friendly and easy as possible.)
- Building an automated taxation system
- Our own digital currency and nationalised banking system
- Online voting/direct democracy platform
- Online medical records
- Online education (for training citizens to know how to build a city, and develop industry), and later on proper universities
- A better real-time budgeting system

We believe we can provide cheap power, water supply and accommodation for citizens ($300 large military tents) to start off settlement, and our citizens are willing to cope with this arrangement of living for a dozen months or so.

We need to quickly develop industry (refineries, construction, servicing, supermarkets, etc), build homes & infrastructure and begin exporting products and services at a competitive rate.

Assume we have a few million in capital allocated for material resources (factories, equipment, raw materials)

Part of our economic value can be generated from our citizen's companies which engage in global digital services such as digital marketing, website development, software and applications and other services that can be fulfilled online, and most would be willing to have this revenue taxed. Regardless, any foreign currency coming into our country will create economic value.

We are willing to harvest the necessary natural resources to do this.

We have very willing volunteers willing to virtually work for free to build the nation initially, and as long as their survival needs, they will be paid in our own currency later

**What could we do to help make us economically independent and self-sufficient?**

*I AM NOT ASKING HOW TO BE INDEPENDENT, I AM ASKING HOW DO WE DEVELOP INDUSTRY (what sort of companies should we start with our limited capital) practical examples*

### Notes

[image: Our claim]

Our claim does include some populated areas, but we are considering them Australian enclaves, and are still fully entitled to their land under our system

Comment: Wow, tents, huh? Maybe even with plumbing! You'll be fending off hordes of would-be citizens, I'm sure.

Comment: You can’t expect to start a settlement with prebuilt infrastructure everywhere, the workers that build that need accomodation

Comment: Have a look at how remote commercial mining or oil and gas drilling developments are started.

Comment: Temporary housing and portable toilets in many cases

Comment: Yep. Not tents. I think your "few million in capital" is probably too low by an order of magnitude or two to get started.

Comment: what is your point? it’s practically the same thing we are using, Also, the few million is purely for material costs. A huge cost in most projects is labour, but that is non-existent for us

Comment: There is no question mark in this aspirational text. What is the question to be answered?

Comment: Labor costs do not exist? That's not really possible. Even if all the workers were slaves, there would still be costs with feeding them, clothing them, whipping them etc.

Comment: @AlexP they have brought stockpiles of food to last a year, they are not slaves and they also have clothes

Comment: "Hundreds of citizens" is not really the scale where self-sufficiency and high technology is possible, that needs many different knowledge-intensive niche specializations that a few hundred can't provide. You could have any two of these factors in the way that you want - self-sufficiency and high technology with a much, much larger population; or you could have a properly self-sufficient campus for hundreds of people that's low-tech; or you could have a high-tech economy for a few hundred people that's heavily reliant on infrastructure provided by some larger entity; but not all three at once.

Comment: I'm VTCing because it seems your question contains the answers.

Answer (score 4):

### There are some big companies that do this already - BHP, Rio Tinto, FMG. They are a corporate example of what you are trying to achieve, but what you are really after is a legal example. This is harder.

Mining companies already have purpose built towns in the desert, with infrastructure sometimes owned by the mining company, even on leased land (such as rail lines to ports). They prefer this to operating out of established towns and infrastructure. Independent infrastructure therefore is not much of a problem.

The reason is a corporation really needs a stable framework of laws that create a stable environment to operate in. Australia already has this, and already provides major tax incentives for mining companies to do this.

So for your nation to exist you do need either **a really strong deficiency in laws** such that it isn't beneficial to create what you want within Australia, or a **really strong argument for it to be located where you want it**, or both.

So perhaps:

- There are Australian Laws which cannot change, that prohibit the industries your describing. Actually, the recently passed [Cyber Security laws](https://www.appknox.com/blog/glance-australias-cyber-security-laws) passed by the Liberal Government (which allow the government access to any data with no privacy) may be a candidate for this, as IT industries in Australia are already up in arms about these laws, as they cannot guarantee security to their customers and must now always have a 'back door'.
- These laws do need to be irreversible though - ie. A Labor government can't just rescind them. Perhaps either they have constitutional presence, or they are physically irreversible (such as infrastructure already installed).
- A strong reason why infrastructure cannot be shared, perhaps security devices are present in Mainland Australia, and none in yours, so it benefits Mainland Australia to have a kind of 'buffer state'?
- A strong reason why governance cannot be shared. Perhaps the Australian Mainland government needs to keep 'at arms length' the buffer state, similar to Manus island where the Government sends Asylum seekers it doesn't want so it can claim abuse on the island are 'not its problem'. It becomes politically positive for the government to have a 'scapegoat' (such as 'it's not our country, we aren't responsible for what goes on there').

Comment: So your entity needs to be well-heeled enough to build infrastructure in the middle of nowhere and import a bunch of specialists, but *not* rich enough to bribe - err, that is, *lobby* the government to let it operate in peace...

Answer (score 4):

**Tax haven.**

This is a time tested method for small countries without too much in the way of resources - Grand Cayman, Cyprus, Switzerland and Panama are all small countries which earn a living receiving the wealth of persons who live in and profit from larger established countries.

You will have banks, and serve as a tax haven for the wealthy of China and the Pacific.  The fact that your citizens are web developers and savvy folks means that leveraging this will be a better bet than having them fish or grow corn.  The fact that somehow Australia is tolerating your presence on its island means that you benefit from the proximity of the Australian military which will cast a dim view on armed raiders coming to attack its little parasite country.

Once you have this money residing with you, you can invest it as banks do.  As regards groceries and services you will do what cash rich and resource poor entities do - outsource them.  Bankers concentrate on banking, not manufacturing their own toilet paper.  You can concentrate on your tax haven business and purchase energy, groceries and the like at marked up prices from your big neighbor Australia.  Which will make you less a parasite than a renter, and might explain why Australia tolerates your country.

---

If this is taking place in the world as we know it, you will of course need some sort of agreement with Australia and the native people who reside in your chosen area up front such that your protocountry is not subject to existing laws and regulations.  If you are hoping to just finesse that aspect that will work as long as you are scrag-bearded separatist computer dudes living in a tent compound.  If you actually start making money or breaking laws or marrying child-wives, local governmental entities will get interested and show up.

Comment: Thanks for not arguing about the idea and getting to the point. Great answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to be *very* integrated with the surrounding country. The examples of microstates such as Grand Cayman or Monaco still have 40000-50000 people; if you have just a few hundred, then you can have *one* small industry and supporting core services (such as basic sanitation, food distribution, retail and governance) takes up all the manpower, you don't have people left to have a decent healthcare system or a higher education system or proper infrastructure. A small village can't get all the services appropriate for a city, no matter how it's organized.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of "**country**", holding sovereign right establishes each country present in the world.  Two components define that.

**De jure**, or *legal*, sovereignty is the theoretical right to exercise exclusive control over one's subjects.

**De facto**, or *actual*, sovereignty is concerned with whether control in fact exists.  This can be approached in two ways:

- Does the governing power have sufficient strength (police, etc.) to compel its subjects to obey it?
- Are the subjects of the governing power in the habit of obeying it?

Generally, to be considered sovereign, you must obtain both **de jure** AND **de facto** control.  Having one or the other alone does not a sovereign (aka country) make.

> In general, as you have outlined your society, they will all starve
>   rather quickly, with their hands on all that technology.

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: Your question: "What could we do to help make us economically independent and self-sufficient?"  Unless you have de jure and de facto, you are not a country, thus you are an odd collection of people engaged in activities under the de jure and de facto of Austrailia.  You can be neither economically independent or able to be self-sufficient.

Comment: Assume we are fully de-jure and de-facto an independent country in this circumstance, perhaps not under Australia, but under our own system

Answer (score 1):

## Just Cause

Well, you mentioned an "information war".  So I'll presume that the rest of Oz has fallen prey to the scourge of authoritarianism, enforced by a powerful propaganda machine that the autocrats use to persecute minorities and suppress dissent, while taking away freedoms.  This helps motivate the "why" of a new country.

## Dependence

There are two ways to declare independence: the most obvious is to be so strong that nobody can challenge you.  This is going to be infeasible for your ragtag band of idealists.  The other way is to be so valuable to others that nobody is willing to mess with you.  So instead of focusing on *independence*, your group should focus on *dependence*.  They should produce such highly valued products that foreign customers will lend diplomatic cover or even military weight to protect your de facto sovereignty.

Now, this is where it gets tricky.  If customers believe they can just buy your companies outright and operate them under Oz law, then your new country is DOA.  You need to make it clear that your employees have a fanatical belief in "New North Ozland" and will quit working before they give up on their dream of establishing a new state.  If their products mediate hundreds of billions of dollars in commerce, then folks will not want that cash cow to get slaughtered.

## Finding Religion

You also want to prevent other companies from poaching your best people and gutting your nascent economy.  This is why there needs to be a strong reason why your people are committing to an undeveloped nation-in-progress when they have the skills to go anywhere they want.  The best way to do this is for your nation to be built on a set of ideals which are unmatched anywhere else, and for your founders to believe in these ideals to a near-irrational, almost religious level.

It would obviously help if your group had a very charismatic leader who could embody and proselytize these values to the faithful and newcomers.  They could also be enforced by new rituals, symbolism, iconography, etc.

## Infiltrate

Ideally, the digital products exported by your new country are sufficiently diverse that even governments wish to buy them.  When you get to the point where the Oz gov't is also a customer, then you have neutralized one of the biggest threats.  At that point, you just need to use good ol' lobbying to get your new legislator friends to introduce bills establishing New North Ozland as a Special Administrative Region with its own oversight and limited jurisdiction of Ozland proper.  After this settles in for a decade or two, you just keep expanding the rights until eventually your country is effectively independent, without anyone really caring or disputing the legal minutia of the fact.

Comment: Great answer, a more machiavellian approach, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> The Northern Territory of Australia, marked in red, has vast areas of minerals such as **gold, uranium, copper, nickel, iron, manganese and rare earth elements** yet to be fully explored and discovered. It is very dry and could benefit hugely from a large scale irrigation program. **Tourism** has a fantastic future there, based around Ayers Rock (Uluru) and Darwin, where military encampments are growing. Australia-USA Alliance. (U.S. Marines, etc.)

---

> Demand is insatiable in Asia for our natural resources. Why should this demand stop? Only a worldwide depression could stop this demand for natural resources to feed the monsters of Asian industry. We have lithium ore (spodumene) to feed into China's waiting lithium carbonate producing plant. (Galaxy Lithium). We have rare earth elements, manganese and nickel. Millions of tonnes of iron ore and copper and more are in the ground. We've mostly sold out or outsourced **our diminishing manufacturing industries that simply cannot compete** with the cheap labour competition in South East Asia.

*Natural Resources in Australia Map*, [australiasearch.net](http://australiasearch.net/map-of-australia-resources-sector-for-post-boom-wealth/)

Some maps show Zinc in what would be your south west corner (other maps show nothing of interest whatsoever, throughout the entire Northern Territory, especially the most northern bit). Australia has the 'goods', they just can't competitively make anything out of them.